# Запятые в предложениях с КАК

Tags: пунктуация, как, обороты-с-как

Помогите, пожалуйста, проверить знаки препинания. Встретила разную расстановку запятых и окончательно запуталась. Нужны ли запятые перед как в данных предложениях?

1. Каждое утро, после того(,) как вы проснётесь, произносите фразу...
2. Он вынужден питаться(,) как ребёнок(,) жидкой, мягкой, лёгкой для переваривания пищей
3. Я(,) как зеркало(,) отражаю всё то, что происходит внутри тебя.
4. Я становлюсь мягким(,) как хлопок.
5. Перед каждым собеседованием и после того(,) как он получал негативный ответ от потенциальных работодателей, у него начинались приступы рвоты.
6. Теперь он знает(,) как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Каждое утро, **после того как вы проснётесь**, произносите фразу...

(2) Он вынужден питаться **как ребёнок** — жидкой, мягкой, лёгкой для переваривания пищей.

(3) Я **как зеркало** отражаю всё то, что происходит внутри тебя.

(4) Я становлюсь мягким, **как хлопок**.

(5) Перед каждым собеседованием и после того, **как он получал негативный ответ от потенциальных работодателей,** у него начинались приступы рвоты.

(6) Теперь он знает, **как это сделать**.

Пояснение

(1) Нет расчленения союза.

(2) и (3) Сравнительный оборот является обстоятельством и  не обособляется, так как нужно исключить значение причины.

(4) Сравнительный оборот обособляется.

(5) Расчленение союза в связи с однородными отношениями (союз И).

(6) Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изэяснительным.

Comment: Дело было вечером...

Comment: Точно, вечером, я это помню. Думаю, вот интересные и нестандартные предложения.Надо поскорее ответить, пока вопрос не закрыли, как раз в 5 минут уложилась (личный рекорд), Теперь штраф, наверное, пришлете?  А ведь говорят, что мы должны делиться знаниями, это же девиз нашего форума. Да и на ДЗ этот набор предложений не очень похож, автор просто подобрал их по своей теме.

Comment: Минусы не ставлю никогда, хотя рука часто тянется к маузеру. Прямая подсказка убивает всякую мотивацию лентяя к самостоятельному поиску решения, и от инстинктов убивать нужно избавляться.

Comment: Да я про модераторов говорю, они могут прислать предупреждение.  Я же считаю, что наш форум преимущественно образовательный, а не конкретно воспитательный для одного человека. Союз КАК  всегда вызывает много вопросов, причем многие задачи  решаются неоднозначно.  Их могут посмотреть другие люди: учиться на решенных практических примерах иногда полезнее, чем  изучать теоретические правила.  Меня же вот что огорчает. Форум - это всё-таки дискуссия, а не мнение одного человека. А вот мои ОДИНОКИЕ ответы безо всяких пометок и без обсуждения могут показаться неубедительными для наших гостей.

Comment: Я не думаю, что борьба с ДЗ должна быть нашей самоцелью. Мне, к примеру, несложно определить, где ДЗ, а где материал, который показался для автора сложным.  К примеру, люди пишут статьи по своей теме, они  не филологи,  но им хочется написать грамотно. К тому же есть темы, которые  интересны широкой аудитории.

Comment: И какая же «у нас» самоцель? Неужели за «всех нас» решите? На борьбе с подсказкой, а не ДЗ, я бы остановился. Это правило сайта.

Comment: Самоцель у нас образовательная, а не воспитательная. Из Правил сайта: "Хорошо, когда ваш вопрос актуален, полезен не только вам, но и другим пользователям".  Я бы актуальность  считала основным критерием качества вопроса.